# ADC build order to reach AS cap in URF mode?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new URF (ultra rapid fire) game mode doubles AS gain from items, making it far easier for Marksmen to reach the 2.5 cap.

What build order should I use to reach this most effectively without wasting gold on getting too much? Should I switch early BTs for some champions with BotRK as it may be more efficient in this mode?

Comment: Also good path for Kayle. Played against one with a Wit's end and Nashor's Tooth and it was brutal. She could 2v1 almost any combination on my team.

Comment: Would this be considered too localized as there is no guarantee URF mode will last longer than a couple weeks? Its a perfectly valid question, but will have no use when they remove the game mode

Comment: @Brian Well the mode is playable and I highly doubt that it's rarely played so there are more than enough people who could answer that question. As you've already mentioned the question itself is 100% valid.

Comment: Also URF seems to be one of those modes they will reenable periodically (another example is One-for-all), so while it's only temporarily available, it will probably be available again in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build depends entirely on your champion. So basically what you want to do is take a look at [this list](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions%27_attack_speed) and search for the champion that you want to play. You will see the amount on AS% that's needed to reach 2.5Atk/S. Now since this is URF you can basically take that amound and divide it by 2. Keep in mind though that some champions have spells that increase their attack speed and If you want to go for a pure 2.5Atk/S build those spells might become useless.

Anyways: now a little example:

I want to play Graves so in normal mode I would need 250.7% AS and here I need 125.35%. As you can see It's impossible to use every single % of Attackspeed because of these numbers. Now If I just wanna go for the 2.5Atk/S with a more or less viable build I would need a Phantom dancer + 50(100)%, a Blade of the ruined king + 40(80)%, Berserkers + 20(40) and another random Attackspeed Item (I think only PD would be viable but also a poor choice).

Keep in mind though that this example also shows a champion that has an attack speed buff which will be on almost no cooldown in URF. This buff also adds 40(80)%. So basically I'd say a Viable build for every champ would be

```
BotrK -> Berserk -> PD -> IE -> BT/LW -> Random Def/Aggressive item
```

because it's absolutely not worth reaching 2.5Atk/S since some AS spells will be useless and you will spend far too much gold on overcapped AS. If you want to get to those 2.5% AS go for a PD as last Item because you will at least gain some crit from it.

Comment: Good point re. the AS booster skills, I hadn't considered that :)